# Error in ASP.NET C# (implicit conversion)

Tags: asp.net

I am new in ASP.NET programming. Please help me.

```
 void DisplayData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //objBuyer.BuyerId = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    **ERROR-->>>**   dt = objBuyer.DisplayData();********
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
        txtBName.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

> ERROR:Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert `void` to a `DataTable`, which is not possible. Your method has to return a `DataTable` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the DisplayData method does not return a DataTable object, it simply displays the data in objBuyer, and returns void.

That's the problem, but I can't really help further than that without some sort of context!

Answer (score 0):

The `DisplayData()` method needs to return a `DataTable` in order for this to work.
A nice and easy tutorial can be found here: http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/data-table-csharp.aspx
As you can see, there's a `DataTable` created and after that's done, several rows are added to the table with the `Rows.Add()` method.